# How to catch keyboard enter key event in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner with C#. I have a button to login into my program. 
How to catch keyboard enter key event this program

Here is my code without enter event handler

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var q = from m in db.Users
            where m.Use_Name == txtUserName.Text && m.Use_Password == txtPassword.Text
            select m;

    if (q.Any())
    {
        Main m1 = new Main();
        m1.Show();
        this.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("username or password is incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code I assume you're in WinForms. If so, you can just set the Form's `AcceptButton` property to your login button. Then, pressing Enter on the form will invoke this handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can write below piece of code :-

```
 if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed", "Attention");                
    }
```

OR

You can designate a button as the `"AcceptButton"` in the Form's properties.

See this:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984346(VS.71).aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText